# Should use "__imp__ApiName@N" or "_ApiName@N"?

Tags: windows, winapi, assembly, x86, name-mangling

I have dumped a Windows SDK .lib file (kernel32.lib) with DUMPBIN, the output show me that there are two "versions" for every API name, for example:

_*imp*_ExitProcess@4

and

_ExitProcess@4

So, why there are two of the same with different name mangling? .
Let say i want to call ExitProcess from NASM, wich of them should i use when declare EXTERN?, mi practice shows me that i can call any of them but i don't know which one is the "correct" or the "prefered" to stick with it.

Comment: `_ExitProcess@4` is [used by a naive compiler](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/07/21/673830.aspx). `__imp_ExitProcess@4` is [used by a less naive compiler](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/07/24/676669.aspx).

Comment: @Raymond Excelent articles. But, is this relevant for asm rdevelopment?, assemblers behave like VS compilers?

Comment: You can choose whether you want your assembly code to be naive or less naive. You can write code the naive way and call `_ExitProcess@4` directly, or you can write it the less naive way and call `__imp__ExitProcess@4` indirectly.

Comment: @Raymond Ok i understand these, now.. what happen when using more simple linkers like ALINK wich only accept import librarys without decorators in the function names (just: "EXTERN ExitProcess") ??, that would be naive too?.

Comment: Consult your linker documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `_imp_` version is meant to be used with `__declspec(dllimport)` on Visual C++ compilers to prevent potential conflicts with code in the same module.

You're not supposed to use that fact explicitly in your code -- just use the original function, i.e. `_ExitProcess@4`.